# Dask : what is the asyncio equivalent of as_completed?

Tags: python-asyncio, dask, dask-distributed

I have a working Dask client code like that :

```py
client = Client(address=self.cluster)

futures = []

for job in jobs:

   future = client.submit(...)
   futures.append(future)

for future, result in as_completed(futures, with_results=True, raise_errors=True):

   key = future.key
   state = (State.FINISHED if result is True else State.FAILED)
   
   ...
```

The Dask `as_completed` function is relevant, because it iterate on job that have finished with the good order.

The problem with that code, is it may block indefinitely on the `as_completed` call, in case of the workers are not available for instance.

Is there a way to rewrite it with `asyncio` ? Indeed, with `asyncio`, I may use the `wait` function with a timeout, in order to unblock blocking call, in case of errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.as_completed` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html