# Dask: as_completed threadlocks with asynchronous=True or access future inside asyncio.as_completed for asynchronous dask

Tags: python, python-asyncio, dask, dask-distributed, concurrent.futures

I am using asyncio.as_completed for a similar use case but I am still trying to figure out how to access future.key through the courotine or asyncio.as_completed(futures)

from distributed import as_completed, futures_of

```
import asyncio
def get_futures(darray: dask.array.core.Array) -> List[distributed.client.Future]:
    darray_persist = darray.persist()
    futures = futures_of(darray_persist )
    return futures


futures = get_futures(darray)
for future in futures:
    # use future.key value

# before
for future, chunk_data in as_completed(futures, with_results=True):
        future.cancel()
        # i want the key value here
        key = future.key

# trying to achieve similar result with asyncio
for idx, coroutine in enumerate(asyncio.as_completed(futures)):
        await coroutine
        # how do I get the key value of the future here
```

asyncio.as_completed = dask's as_completed asyncio equivalent - [Dask : what is the asyncio equivalent of as_completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824332/dask-what-is-the-asyncio-equivalent-of-as-completed)

```
# you can run this in a jupyter notebook
from distributed import Client, as_completed, futures_of
client = await Client(asynchronous=True)
client
import dask.array as da
arr = da.random.uniform(size=(128,)*3, chunks=(32,)*3)
arr
# futures = futures_of(client.persist(arr))
futures = futures_of(arr.persist())

# this works but afaik has no way to access future.key
from asyncio import as_completed
for future_coro in as_completed(futures):
    print(future_coro)

#this gets threadlocked
from distributed import as_completed

for future in as_completed(futures):
    key = future.key
    result = await future
    await client.cancel(future)
```

I tried to avoid using the future.key value inside the loop but that made it more complex, so looking to see if it's possible to get the future.key value inside.

I also tried to see if it's possible to get any key values of coroutines that I can access outside the loop so that i could avoid using future.key and use coroutine.key for example

Attributes that are present in dir(futures), dir(coroutine )
{'**setattr**', '**ne**', '**str**', '**ge**', '**sizeof**', '**await**', '**init**', '**dir**', '**getattribute**', '**lt**', '**class**', '**format**', '**repr**', '**le**', '**eq**', '**reduce**', '**hash**', '**delattr**', '**doc**', '**del**', '**subclasshook**', '**gt**', '**init_subclass**', '**new**', '**reduce_ex**'}

Attributes that are present in only dir(futures)
{'release', '**weakref**', '**dict**', '**module**', 'executor', '_cleared', '_cb_executor_pid', 'status', '**getstate**', '*repr_html*', 'type', '**setstate**', 'client', 'retry', '_cb_executor', '_traceback', '_generation', 'traceback', 'key'}

Attributes that are present in only dir(coroutine )
{'cr_await', 'send', '**name**', 'cr_origin', '**qualname**', 'close', 'cr_frame', 'throw', 'cr_running', 'cr_code'}